# Recursively printing the file paths of all files in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: c, recursion, directory, traversal

I am working on a project which is supposed to print out all the file paths for all the files in a directory and all its sub directories in C. Basically, it's meant in the end to emulate the find utility in Linux.

I have the following code:

```
void read_sub(char * sub_dir){
    DIR *sub_dp = opendir(sub_dir);//open a directory stream
    struct dirent * sub_dirp;//define
    struct stat buf;//define a file status structure
    char temp1[]=".";
    char temp2[]="..";
    char temp3[]="/";

    if(sub_dp!=NULL){ //Check if the directory opened successfully 

        while((sub_dirp=readdir(sub_dp))!=NULL){ //until we've read every entry one by one

            char * temp = sub_dirp -> d_name; //get the name 

            if(strcmp(temp, temp1)!=0 && strcmp(temp, temp2)!=0){ //Ignores . and .. in the directory

                char *temp_sub = temp3; // This is '/'
                temp_sub = strcat(temp_sub, temp); // Adds '/' before the name of the entry


                //now you can add the / in front of the entry's name
                char* temp_full_path=malloc(sizeof(char)*2000); //Create a variable to hold the full path

                //Place the passed directory at the front of the path and add the name of the file to the end
                temp_full_path=strcpy(temp_full_path,sub_dir); 
                strcat(temp_full_path,temp_sub);

                //try to open the file path we just created
                DIR * subsubdp = opendir(temp_full_path);


                //if not null, we've found a subdirectory, otherwise it's a file
                if(subsubdp!=NULL){
                        //close the stream because it'll be reopened in the recursive call.
                    closedir(subsubdp);
                    read_sub(temp_full_path);//call the recursive function call.
                }else{
                    printf("%s\n",temp_full_path);
                }
            }
        }//end of while loop
        closedir(sub_dp);//close the stream
    }else{
        printf("cannot open directory\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}
```

I'm running this by directly passing it "testdir",which is a directory with the following structure:

```
testdir/
|-- dir1
| |-- dir2
| | |-- test5
| | `-- test6
| |-- test3
| `-- test4
|-- dir3
| |-- test7
| `-- test8
|-- test1
`-- test2
```

Thus, it should output something like:

```
testdir/dir1/dir2/test5
testdir/dir1/dir2/test6
testdir/dir1/test3
testdir/dir1/test4
```

And so on. However, the actual result is:

```
testdir/dir1/dir2/test6
testdir/dir1/dir2/test6test5
testdir/dir1/dir2test3
testdir/dir1/dir2test3test4
testdir/dir1test1
testdir/dir1test1dir3
testdir/dir1test1dir3test2
```

So it seems that it may not be properly clearing the full file path when it's running is my guess? Also, it doesn't seem to actually be entering dir3 to print test7 and test8. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: First thing that looks bad, using `strcat()`

Comment: Use DFS or BFS method to print paths of all files and directories of a directory.

Comment: As always, the sane thing to do would be to use the `*at()`-family of file/directory functions in POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating sufficient space for the target strings. You need at least `PATH_MAX` bytes.

Try

```
char temp1[PATH_MAX] = ".";
char temp2[PATH_MAX] = "..";
char temp3[PATH_MAX] = "/";
```

As it was, the compiler will only allocate enough space to hold the initialization string, (2, 3, 2) respectively. So your program was exhibiting undefined behavior. I would recommend `snprintf()` instead of `strcat()` as it's direct and not as expensive. With `strcat()` every time you call it, it will search for the current end of the target string iterating until it finds the terminating `'\0'`.

Also, try to use the least number of levels of indentation because the code becomes quickly very unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `S_ISDIR` to test for directory. `malloc` should be cleaned up with `free` to avoid memory leak. It can get too complicated to implement `malloc/free` in a recursive function, so it's better to just declare a temporary buffer `path[4096]`. This works as long as path name is not too long. If path is too long then the safest thing option is to print error and not continue.

For `"."` and `".."` you can declare

```
const char *temp1 = ".";
const char *temp2 = "..";
```

This way you avoid accidentally writing to `temp1` and `temp2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void read_sub(char *subdir)
{
    DIR *dirp = opendir(subdir);
    if (!dirp)
        return;

    struct dirent *dentry;
    while ((dentry = readdir(dirp)) != 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(dentry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dentry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        printf("%s/", subdir);

        char path[4096];
        int len = strlen(subdir) + 1 + strlen(dentry->d_name) + 1;
        if (len >= sizeof(path)) 
        {
            printf("path is too long...\n");
            break;
        }
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", subdir, dentry->d_name);

        struct stat st;
        stat(path, &st);
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
        {
            printf("%s\n", dentry->d_name);
            read_sub(path);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n",dentry->d_name);
        }
    }

    closedir(dirp);
}
```

Alternatively you can use variable length array for `path`

```
int len = strlen(subdir) + 1 + strlen(dentry->d_name) + 1;
char path[len];
sprintf(path, "%s/%s", subdir, dentry->d_name);
```